# Data Only Returned For 1st DB Call

Tags: php, html

I am populating 4 selects with the same query but only the 1st select gets populated and the sub-sequent ones do not.  Matter of fact once it reaches the second select page_load() stops.  
**Questions:**
1) What is causing page_load to stop?
2) Is there a way to re-use code so that I do not have to make multiple DB Calls to return the same data?

Here is my syntax:

```
<div id="OrderInfo" runat="server">
<table id="orderinginfo">
<tr>
<td>
    <label for="labelselect">Choose an Item</label>
    <select>
        <option value="null" selected="selected"></option>
        <?php 
            include 'phpquery.php';
            $sql = "Select item from items";
            echo get_items($sql); 
        ?>
    </select>                   
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <label for="labelselect1">Choose an Item:</label>
    <select>
        <option value="null" selected="selected"></option>
        <?php 
            include 'phpquery.php';
            $sql = "Select item from items";
            echo get_items($sql); 
        ?>
    </select>                   
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<?php
function get_items($sql) {
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "user";
  $password = "pass";
  $dbname = "database";
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  if ($conn->connect_error) { die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); }  
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
  {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { echo "<option value=".$row['item'].">".$row['item']."</option><br>"; }
  } 
  else echo "<option value='null'>default</option>";
  $conn->close();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are re-defining any function or class in `phpquery.php`. PHP aborts when you try to redefine such a function or class. Consider including that file `phpquery.php` once and then run your function `get_items`. You can use `include_once` or `require_once`.

`require_once()` and `include_once()` statement can be used to include a php file in another one, when you may need to include the called file more than once. If it is found that the file has already been included, calling script is going to ignore further inclusions.

Comment: Can the include statement be added anywhere in the .php file or must it be used directly above the calling procedure?

Comment: Is your function `get_items` inside `phpquery.php`?

Comment: Yes, my function get_items is inside phpquery.php

Comment: Then you can include the file anywhere before calling the `get_items` function.